# How to implement a table with multiple colums filter and QPushButton on each row?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside, pyqt5

I'm stuck. With `QTableView` + `QStandartItemModel` + `QSortFilterProxyModel` I can only add 1 `QLineEdit` for 1 specific column `line_edit.textChanged.connect(filter_model.setFilterRegExp)`. Moreover I can't figure out how to add widget item to QTableView but only to QTableWidget (which i can't use because of filter?). I may give up the idea of adding widget and just make my whole row open another dialog on double click.But still I don't understand how to filter multiple columns **at the same time**. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Moreover I can't figure out how to add widget item to QTableView

You need use `QtGui.QItemDelegate` for such thing. Have a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/kaotika/0efcd01f1f835e55bf94) nice code snippet (not mine). And please read Qt manual about [QItemDelegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#details) and [Model View Delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) pattern.